# vertical align with video tag

Tags: css, html5-video

I'm trying to vertical align a `<video>` tag. I found the following article, which seems promising, but no luck:

http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

To keep the aspect ratio, I've got the CSS like this:

```
video {
    min-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:black;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

So the effect is to make the video horizontally across the browser, and vertically as tall as it can be to fit the aspect ratio. That leaves some black space at the bottom of the browser window, so to look nice I want to center the video element leaving equal black space above and below.

The suggestion at the link is:

```
video {
    top:50%;
    position:relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* and all the browser variants of this */
}
```

The result, across a few browsers, is to move the video up 50% (from translateY), but it doesn't do anything with top:50%, so the video is half off-screen.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Note: I also tried the suggestion in the comment about `display:table-cell` which also didn't work.

Comment: one clarification is that if I do `top:350px` I get roughly the right effect, so for some reason the `top:50%` is not doing what it's supposed to. I think the problem is that the percentage specified is of the parent element (`body` in this case) but I need it to be 50% of the `window.innerHeight` which may not be possible.

Comment: try `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;` to video.

Comment: actually what worked, was adding a single line of JS, to set the body.height = window.innerHeight. Then top behaves the way it's supposed to. I'm pretty sure that solution I posted was assuming your content is in a fixed size container (some outer div with width & height).

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, the body needed to have height. At first I did this via jQuery, e.g. something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // actually more complicated than this, because window.innerHeight isn't
    // available on all browsers...
    $('body').height(window.innerHeight);
});
```

But then a co-worker pointed out that I would now have to handle resizing as well. He suggested the alternative CSS only solution which also works:

```
html,body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```